# javascript function to get all images in html

Tags: javascript

I wanted to have a javascript function to basically return an array of all the img src there is in a page, how do I do this?

Comment: What did you try? Show the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can easily get an array containing all `img` elements via [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

Instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` you could also use the `document.images` collection.

---

If you are using jQuery, you can also use `$('img')` which gives you a jQuery object containing all `img` elements.

```
var srcList = $('img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Comment: variable `images` is an array of DOMElement named `img`, i.e. `<img>` tag. Need to further extract the `src` attribute.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice him asking about the src values. Answer updated.

Comment: another for loop syntax `for(var i in images ){
  srcList.push(images[i].src);
}`

Comment: @GaboEsquivel: That's enumeration syntax, which shouldn't be used when you want to iterate indices.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor—[document.images](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) is an [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506), not an array. The only similarities they have is that they both have members that can be accessed by numeric index and a special length property.

Comment: @amnotiam thanks, now I know it should only be used to iterate over object properties.

Comment: Does this technique work when the image tags are dynamically created via other JS scripting? I suppose once it's in the DOM, it doesn't matter how it got there, yes?

Answer (score 14):

There is a [document.images](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) collection, so:

```
function allSrc() {
  var src = [];
  var imgs = document.images;
  for (var i=0, iLen=imgs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    src[i] = imgs[i].src;
  }
  return src;
}
```

#### Edit Update for ECMAScript ES5

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.images,function(img){return img.src});
```

If you have ES6 arrow functions available:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.images, img => img.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to find all of the image tags. The jQuery code will be as follows:

```
images = []
$('img').each(function(idx, img) {
    images.push(img.src)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is old however just wanted to add that you can one line it:

```
images = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), null);
```

I'm not sure of cross browser support.

Comment: If you replace `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` with `document.images` it will be 21 characters shorter and faster. And if you use *reduce* you can return the actual *src* attribute values rather than the images (which is what the OP wants) ;-)